# Building Windows 10 Mobile app using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: msbuild, uwp, azure-devops, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to build Windows 10 Mobile app (UWP) using Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) build system, however it fails with error:

> Could not find SDK "WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.14393.0".

How can I solve this? Does it need any special setting? I think it's related to the "Windows Mobile Extension for the UWP" that is referenced in the solution.

Comment: Probably related to [Could not find SDK SQLite.UWP.2015 when building UWP application using Hosted TFS pool](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37070617/1889329).

Comment: Are you using hosted build agent and can you share your build definition?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I'm using hosted build agent. How can I share the build def?

Comment: @user969153 What's the result now? Do you succeed building your project with on-premise build agent?

Comment: @starain I don't want to build with on-premise agent, that's not an option for me. I want to build this in cloud.

Comment: @user969153 I submitted a user voice, you can vote it and track updates of Hosted Agent.

Answer (score 0):

The 14393 SDK (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) is the newest SDK that isn’t available on the Hosted Agent, so the build will be failed. You can set up a build agent with Windows 10 SDK be installed to build the project.

For on-premise build agent, you need to install windows 10 SDK on your build agent.

Update:

I submit a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16113535-include-windows-10-sdk-on-visual-studio-team-servi) that you could vote.

Comment: How can I "set up a build agent with Windows 10 SDK be installed" pls?

Comment: You can't install windows 10 SDK in hosted build agent, it will be updated by Microsoft. As I said that you need to set up a build agent on your machine that windows 10 SDK has been installed.

Comment: @user969153 You can refer to this link to deploy your own build agent: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows and then you can install Win10 SDK on it.