# References not included in VSTS

Tags: tfs, uwp, azure-pipelines

I'm building an UWP Windows 10 in XAML and C#. 
I have several extensions installed into VS2017 that are referenced from the "references" section.
Because the VS2017 host agent doesn't have the extensions I had to copy to a local folder and distribute the extensions with the source code. 
I put this code in the CSProj in order to get access to the extensions by the folder.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>..\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs;
      </SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

In order to simulate the process, I compile using powershell my App using MSBuild 15. When fetching the SDKs in the powershell compilation it  runes 6 steps, 3 to enumerate and 3 to add the SDKs to the project:

```
ExpandSDKReferences:  Enumerating SDK Reference "Microsoft.VCLibs, 
ersion=14.0" from "C:\Users\myusername\Source\Repos\VSTS\BI Read 
Windows\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs\Windows 
Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\".
Enumerating SDK Reference "PDFTron.PDFNetUWPApps, Version=6.5.4.47152" from 
"C:\Users\myusername\Source\Repos\VSTS\BI Read Windows\SDKs\Microsoft 
SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\PDFTron.PDFNetUWPApps\6.5.4.47152\".
Adding reference "References\CommonConfiguration\x86\pdftron.winmd".
Adding file "Redist\CommonConfiguration\x86\pdftron.dll" from redist folder 
with target path "pdftron.dll".
Enumerating SDK Reference "SQLCipher.UAP.2015, Version=3.4.0" from 
"C:\Users\myusername\Source\Repos\VSTS\BI Read Windows\SDKs\Microsoft 
SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLCipher.UAP.2015\3.4.0\".
Adding file "Redist\Debug\x86\sqlite3.dll" from redist folder with target 
path "sqlite3.dll".
```

In the other hand, in the hosted agent in VSTS it only ENUMERATES the sdks but never gets to add them to the project:

```
 ExpandSDKReferences:
 Enumerating SDK Reference "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0" from 
 "C:\a\1\s\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs\Windows 
Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\".
Enumerating SDK Reference "PDFTron.PDFNetUWPApps, Version=6.5.4.47152" from 
"C:\a\1\s\SDKs\Microsoft 
SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\PDFTron.PDFNetUWPApps\6.5.4.47152\".
Enumerating SDK Reference "SQLCipher.UAP.2015, Version=3.4.0" from 
"C:\a\1\s\SDKs\Microsoft 
SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs\SQLCipher.UAP.2015\3.4.0\".
```

And because it's not added, I've got compilation errors. What might be happening?

Regards.

Comment: What's the path of the extension reference? Specify SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot is not working for me, could you share a simple projects on the OneDrive?

Comment: I'm just following this samples https://cmatskas.com/tfs-continuous-integration-for-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-sdk-dependencies/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070617/could-not-find-sdk-sqlite-uwp-2015-when-building-uwp-application-using-hosted-tf https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/461 In theory according to the GitHub  thread it work. And It finds properly the SDKs. But what I don't see working is the  "Adding reference" step. I'll try to make a project later.

Comment: Could you build the project on a machine that do not install that extension manually? (I get the error of Cannot find assembly sqlite3.dll, but it actually exists)

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. I have a VS2017 locally that works perfect, with 2 extensions referenced from the LOCAL folder that I added and with the SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot tweak. If it doesn't work you could try  <SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>..\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs;$(SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot)</SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>. I compile the project in VS2017 pressing play and works. I compile it through Powershell and MSBuild and works perfect (it adds the sdks) but the host agent doesn't add them.

Comment: I mean build the project on another machine manually that do not install the necessary extension (e.g. SQLite). Specify SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot is working now, but it seems require some managed resources. What's the detail error of the build?

Comment: The only errors I get is compilation errors because the SDK was not added. Locally the powershell scripts ENUMERATES the SDKs, and then ADDS them . As far as I can see in the host agent, the ENUMARATION step is done but the  ADD step is not , and thus I have compilation errors because the SDK was not added.

Comment: Do you have another machine that not install these extensions' packages? What's the result if you build the project on that machine?

Comment: That it cannot find the SDKs

Comment: So, same error? I recommend that you can setup a on premise build agent.

Comment: I'm doing that with jenkins. But where can I find more information on how to set up an on premise build agent?

Comment: You can refer to this article to setup a on premise build agent. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows (it's easy)

Comment: What's the result if you build the project with your build agent?

Comment: Hi, I read the link and I don't get it, how do I install my software inside? Do I have to connect to it remotely?

Comment: It is used to setup a new build agent on your machine instead of install software on hosted agent. (Download the build agent, then configure it on your machine)

Comment: Hi, I already managed to do it with a couple of scripts in powershell and Jenkins Pipelines. I'll use only VSTS to publish the artifacts. In any case, I think most of the Windows Apps have extensions, so It would be nice if VSTS provides an easy way to handle them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We can't install any software on Hosted agent, so we just can build the project on hosted agent, which doesn't need to install additional software, sdk or package. Regarding for windows app extension, we need to make sure it can be built without install corresponding sdk (build fine on a local machine that doesn't install corresponding sdk). If so many users need to use special software, sdk or package, we can submit the user voice, then Hosted agent may include them.

Comment: You said "I already managed to do it with a couple of scripts in powershell and Jenkins Pipelines", did you run powershell on another machine that doesn't install these SDKs, also is Jenkins build agent on another machine that doesn't install these SDKs?

Comment: I mean, every plugin you buy for Windows 10 is sold as a VS extension, which make very annoying to integrate with CI. If you make a Hello app you wont probably need this extensions, thing but I bet every serious app that uses Sqlite, or anything will have the same problems. I have a couple of powershell scripts in a Virtual Machine with jenkins pipelines that restores and compiles the nuget packages and because it's a windows machine, I could install properly the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so, I submit a user voice here: [SQLite for Universal Windows Platform on Hosted VS2017 agent](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18923821-sqlite-for-universal-windows-platform-on-hosted-vs), you can vote and follow up it.

The workaround is that you can setup a build agent on your machine and use it for your builds.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Comment: Hi thanks for the ticket, but It'll be nice  to be a generic extension support.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda You can vote the user voice and follow up it to check the update.